# How to assign data from response objects to object

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi guys I want to ask you about verry basic question, my API server is returning [response from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsEVL.png)

In my angular service I am making successfull request to get this data from server:

```
get() {
        return this._$http({
            url: `${this._AppConstants.api}/calendar`,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(
            (res) => {
                 let events = [];
                 return res.data;
            }
        )
    }
```

But I want to assign response to my `events` object. Let's say my server is returning (as you can see in the screenshot) the objects but I want to transform them to look something like this:

```
{
title: res.data.description,
startsAt: res.data.startdate,
endsAt: res.data.enddate
}
```

I dont have any idea how to transform the objects from server to working arrays

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use observables and an approach like this:

```
    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

The map operator on the observable maps the response to an array of product objects as defined in the IProduct interface.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you exactly want, you could just pass in a new object.

```
events.push({
  title: res.data.description,
  startsAt: res.data.startdate,
  endsAt: res.data.enddate
})
```

Keep in mind, your `events` variable is declared inside of your `.then()` function, so it won't expose its value(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could return an observable:
events.service.ts

```
events(){
    return this.http.get(this.eventsUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    }
```

and then subscribe to it in your component:
event.component.ts

```
export class EventComponent{
  events = []      
  constructor(private eventSvc:EventService){
    eventSvc.subscribe(
      events => this.events = events
    )
  }
}
```